# Firefox add-on's weird behaviour

Tags: exception, xul, preference

I have a preference entry and use below statement to access it's content

```
var st = easyfa.branch.getComplexValue("mapstr",Components.interfaces.nsIPrefLocalizedString).data;
```

this throws exception:

```
*Component returned failure code: 0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIPrefBranch.getComplexValue]*
```

But after setting value of the preference manually (by entering about:config) the error disappears!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of a localised preference must be a chrome URL to a `.properties` file, in which the preference is looked up to locate the resulting string. Assuming the URL points to a locale file, this allows the value to change depending on the installed language.

However you seem to want a simple string preference, which you should retrieve using the `nsISupportsString` interface.

Comment: Having changed nsIPrefLocalizedString to nsISupportsString fixed every thing! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the value of a preference that isn't set will always throw.  You have to wrap it in a `try-catch` block and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, but it would throw `NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED`, not `NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI`.

Comment: In another answer Neil explains that because you are using `nsIPrefLocalizedString` as your type in `getComplexValue`, it's trying to make a URI.  Basically, what happens is the back-end tries to create a uri from an empty string, which results in that throwing.